# Using before the fact in multiple contexts

Tags: phrase-usage, legalese, non-standard

The terms "before the fact" and "after the fact" are usually used in a legal sense, as in, *accessory before the fact*, (and similarly, *accessory after the fact*), to indicate a person aiding or abetting a crime before it is actually committed.

My question is, can these terms be used in a non-legal context, as in, for instance, *learning before the fact*, to imply something learned before its actual use is anticipated?

Comment: That particular example would be rather unusual - I can't say I've heard it. However I can think of instances where I might use "after the fact" with a note of irony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Before the fact" appears rare, and I was only able to find a few examples:

> We train ourselves how to survive before the fact. ([HBR.org](https://hbr.org/2002/05/how-resilience-works))
>
> There are "before-the-fact" moral judgments, and there are "after-the-fact" moral judgments. ([Moral Judgements](http://www3.sympatico.ca/saburns/pg0460.htm))
>
> a thorough investigation may uncover hazards or problems that can be eliminated "before-the-fact" for the future. ([OH&S](https://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/hsprograms/basic.html))

Notably, two of these put "before the fact" in quotation marks. It appears that "before the fact" is not *invalid* outside of a legal context, but it will be less familiar to the average speaker; "beforehand" or "in advance" are examples of more common alternatives.

"After the fact" is much more common - [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/after+the+fact) includes a few different citations of it outside a legal context.